# CSS apply border to a cloud shape?

Tags: css, border, shapes, css-shapes

I drew a cloud via CSS3 using different `div` tags  I am trying to  add a border to the whole shape but I am having trouble since every shape get its own border how can I apply a border to the whole cloud?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cloud">
  <div id="bottom_c"></div>
  <div id="right_c"></div>
  <div id="left_c"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: #4ca3ff;
}
#cloud {
  position: absolute;

}
#bottom_c {
  position: relative; top: 200px; left: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid 5px black;
  z-index: 100;
}
#right_c{
  position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 640px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 5px black;
}
#left_c{
  position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 550px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 5px black;
}
```

**Image:**

[image: CSS cloud shape]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it without any additional elements. Just use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements with the same size and round shape as the top cloud bubbles. `z-index` keeps everything in the right layer.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### CSS:

```css
body{
    background-color: #4ca3ff;
}

#cloud {
    height: 230px;
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

#cloud div {
    border: solid 5px black;
}

#bottom_c {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#right_c{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 140px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 40px; 
    width: 150px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#left_c{
    background-color: #fff;  
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 70px; 
    width: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#cloud::before {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 100px;
    left: 55px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 75px; 
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cloud::after {
    position: absolute; top: 45px; left: 145px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="cloud">
  <div id="bottom_c"></div>
  <div id="right_c"></div>
  <div id="left_c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man the code looks nice and clean i noticed that i was using too much elements and tricks

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the original solution! I needed to create multiple clouds and dynamically resize and recolor them, so I adapted to original solution as follows:

1. I made the clouds resizable by using percentages values for the height, width, top and left properties. The .cloud class uses padding-top to adjust the height of the cloud relative to the cloud's width.
2. I made the :before and :after pseudo-elements divs.
3. I changed the id selectors to class selectors
4. And I reorganized the properties so they're easier to read.

I hope this helps someone. Here's the code:

#### Output

I don't yet have the reputation to post images :/. So here's a link to the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9xQY.jpg

#### CSS:

```
.cloud {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 57.5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cloud_bottom,
.cloud_left,
.cloud_right {
    border: solid 5px black; 
}

.cloud_bottom,
.cloud_left,
.cloud_right,
.cloud_leftCircle,
.cloud_rightCircle {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.cloud_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43.48%;
    height: 65.2%;
    width: 87.5%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.cloud_left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30.43%;
    left: 12.5%;
    height: 43.48%;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.cloud_right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17.39%; 
    left: 35%;
    height: 65.2%;
    width: 37.5%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.cloud_leftCircle {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 32.61%;
    left: 13%;
    height: 43.48%;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cloud_rightCircle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.48%;
    left: 35%;
    height: 65.21%;
    width: 37.5%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="firstCloud cloud">
    <div class="cloud_bottom"></div>
    <div class="cloud_left"></div>
    <div class="cloud_right"></div>
    <div class="cloud_leftCircle"></div>
    <div class="cloud_rightCircle"></div>
</div>

<div class="secondCloud cloud">
    <div class="cloud_bottom"></div>
    <div class="cloud_left"></div>
    <div class="cloud_right"></div>
    <div class="cloud_leftCircle"></div>
    <div class="cloud_rightCircle"></div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function updateCloudColor(cloudElement, color) {
    cloudElement.children().css("background-color", color);
}

$(window).load(function () {
    updateCloudColor($(".firstCloud"), "red");
    updateCloudColor($(".secondCloud"), "blue");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work on codepen or jsfiddle. I set the js framework as jQuery. What to do?