# Add text to the bubbles in a CSS made diagram for a web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, design-patterns

I have created a basic star topology diagram using simple CSS and HTML. I have 2 problems with the code I have:

1. When I try to add text to the bubbles, it overflows from the bubble and the text is not oriented based on the bubble.
2. Instead of a simple bubble I would like a cloud shape.

Any suggestions/solutions would be highly appreciated.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure {
  --containerWidth: 500px;
  --containerHeight: 500px;
  width: var(--containerWidth);
  height: var(--containerHeight);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

figure div {
  background: gray;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

figure .connected-device {
  --connectedDeviceWidth: 100px;
  --connectedDeviceHeight: 100px;
  width: var(--connectedDeviceWidth);
  height: var(--connectedDeviceHeight);
  position: absolute;
  background: gold;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: calc(var(--connectedDeviceHeight) / 2) calc(var(--containerHeight) / 2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure .connected-device::before {
  content: '';
  height: calc((var(--containerHeight) / 2) - var(--connectedDeviceHeight));
  display: block;
  border-right: 2px dashed grey;
  position: relative;
  top: var(--connectedDeviceHeight);
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(calc(1 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(calc(2 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(calc(3 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(calc(4 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(calc(5 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(calc(6 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}

figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(calc(7 / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
}
```

```html
<figure style="--number-connectedDevices: 8">
  <div class="central-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add text to the diagram so that it reproduces the behavior you are experiencing. Be specific about the behavior you desire, and what you've done to try to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: As you are rotating to place the bubbles, you need any text inside a bubble to be in its own element which you rotate back (assuming you want the text in all cases to be the 'normal' way up.

Comment: There is quite a bit on creating cloud shapes if you search around - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919053/creating-a-responsive-cloud-shape

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is not responsive so this snippet alters things slightly by setting CSS variables - the width of the whole and of the bubbles being calculated. The maximum width is set at 500px as in the question but on narrower viewports this will become the width of the viewport (100vw).

Added text needs to be inside its own element so that it can be rotated back to be horizontal.

The rotation setting is put in just once - using the position of the element --n to calculate the actual degrees.

Just for demo the cloud is added as a background png image (this one is allowed for personal use only) but you may like to look into using a base64 image so you don't need a separate file, and the image will be more responsive to different viewport sizes. It is added on a pseudo element so that it too can be rotated back to a horizontal position.

```html
<style>
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  figure {
    --containerWidth: min(500px, 90vw);
    --containerHeight: var(--containerWidth);
    width: var(--containerWidth);
    height: var(--containerHeight);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  figure>div {
    background: gray;
    width: calc(var(--containerWidth) * 140 / 500);
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device {
    --connectedDeviceWidth: calc(100 / 500 * var(--containerWidth));
    --connectedDeviceHeight: var(--connectedDeviceWidth);
    width: var(--connectedDeviceWidth);
    height: var(--connectedDeviceHeight);
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: calc(var(--connectedDeviceHeight) / 2) calc(var(--containerHeight) / 2);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device>div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device::after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCQAK.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    transform: rotate(calc((var(--n) - 1) / var(--number-connectedDevices) * -360deg));
  }
  
  figure .connected-device::before {
    content: '';
    height: calc((var(--containerHeight) / 2) - var(--connectedDeviceHeight));
    display: block;
    border-right: 2px dashed grey;
    position: absolute;
    /* note change */
    top: var(--connectedDeviceHeight);
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(n) {
    transform: rotate(calc((var(--n) - 1) / var(--number-connectedDevices) * 360deg));
  }
  /* rotate the inner text back */
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(n)>div {
    transform: rotate(calc((var(--n) - 1) / var(--number-connectedDevices) * -360deg));
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(2) {
    --n: 2;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(3) {
    --n: 3;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(4) {
    --n: 4;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(5) {
    --n: 5;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(6) {
    --n: 6;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(7) {
    --n: 7;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(8) {
    --n: 8;
  }
  
  figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(9) {
    --n: 9;
  }
</style>
<figure style="--number-connectedDevices: 8">
  <div class="central-device"></div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="connected-device">
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this looks very nice. 1 question, how can I make the size of the clouds based on the text that will come inside of it? Some clouds will have large text data while some will have small. Any suggestions? @A Haworth

Comment: You haven't described a fully defined problem. Are there any constraints or could the connected-device be as wide as the content, or is the content required to fit (in some way) a square etc. Also, this is a new problem so perhaps you should ask it in a new question rather than tack it onto this one.

Comment: Hi sir, no there are no constraints, the connected-device be as wide as the content. If it's not a big change to your code, if possible can you pls suggest the solution here itself or else I will create a new question. Thanks!

Comment: If there are no constraints then you are in danger of the elements overlapping or going out of the viewport. I suspect you need to think through what the practical implications are - especially for narrow viewports. This is where others have rightly asked for fuller HTML - with examples of the sort of text you want to include. 'Hello' is one thing, but a paragraph is another!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt.

If each `.connected-device` had a sub-container, then I could rotate that in the opposite direction, but since that's not the HTML given, instead I've used rotation for the stalks/lines/::before and translate for each `.connected-device`.

Not everything is calculated and that is because to work out the translations nicely, I would have to use trigonometric functions such as [sin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/sin) and these are relatively new and so could cause some issues with browser compatibility.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure {
  --containerWidth: 500px;
  --containerHeight: 500px;
  width: var(--containerWidth);
  height: var(--containerHeight);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

figure div {
  background: gray;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

figure .connected-device {
  --connectedDeviceWidth: 100px;
  --connectedDeviceHeight: 100px;
  --connectedStalkLength: 100px;
  width: var(--connectedDeviceWidth);
  height: var(--connectedDeviceHeight);
  position: absolute;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(var(--translateX), var(--translateY));
}

figure .connected-device::before {
  content: '';
  height: var(--connectedStalkLength);
  display: block;
  border-right: 2px dashed grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--connectedDeviceHeight) / 2);
  transform-origin: top;
  transform:
      rotate(calc(var(--device-number) * 45deg))
      translate(0, calc(var(--connectedDeviceHeight) / 2));
}

figure .connected-device {
  --device-number: 1;
  --translateX: 150px;
  --translateY: -150px;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(2) {
  --device-number: 2;
  --translateX: 150px;
  --translateY: 0;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(3)  {
  --device-number: 3;
  --translateX: 150px;
  --translateY: 150px;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(4)  {
  --device-number: 4;
  --translateX: 0;
  --translateY: 200px;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(5)  {
  --device-number: 5;
  --translateX: -150px;
  --translateY: 150px;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(6)  {
  --device-number: 6;
  --translateX: -200px;
  --translateY: 0;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(7)  {
  --device-number: 7;
  --translateX: -200px;
  --translateY: -200px;
  --connectedStalkLength: 200px;
}
figure .connected-device:nth-of-type(8)  {
  --device-number: 8;
  --translateX: 0;
  --translateY: -200px;
}
```

```html
  <figure style="--number-connectedDevices: 8">
    <div class="central-device"></div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello all</div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello </div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello</div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello</div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello</div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello</div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello</div>
    <div class="connected-device">hello<br>all</div>
  </figure>
```